# How to Write, Read and Append?

Tags: python, list, file

I want to create a file function that when called by main will create a list, read it and append to it , so this is my code so far :

```
def Write():
    cars = ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Renault", "Ford"]
    cars = str(cars)
    candy = ["lollipop", "cupcake", "chocolate", "marshmallow"]
    candy = str(candy)

    infile = open("llist.txt",'w')
    infile.write = cars
    infile.write = candy
    infile.close()

def Read():
    infile = open("llist.txt",'r')
    lines = infile.readline()
    cars = lines[0,1,2,3]
    print(cars)
    infile.close()

def Append():
    infile = open("llist.txt",'a')
    singers = ["Lady Gaga", "Britney Spears", "Christina Aguilera"]
    bruno = ["Bruno Mars"]
    singers = singers.append(bruno)
    directions = str(directions)
    infile.write = (directions)
    infile.close()

def Main():
    Write()
    Read()
    Append()
```

My problem is that when I open the text file itself none of the lists that I have converted as strings have been printed ... Please tell me what I'm doing  wrong, so i can fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing anything to file, You are assigning string to write function, instead of calling it. So, instead of:

```
infile.write = cars
infile.write = candy
```

use this:

```
infile.write(cars)
infile.write(candy)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Besides this , what else do you think I should change ?